# SharePoint Online quick lunch expand button doesn't always work (sometimes has to be clicked twice at least to work)

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, quick-launch

Has anyone encountered the issue, when they have expandable links in their SPO quick lunch navigation (you know, with up / down arrows to expand / collapse sublevel links, that the sub-content doesn't get expanded after the very first click, but the user has to click multiple times (at least twice) to make it work? If yes, are there any ways known to correct the behavior? I've found none so far.

Comment: hi @Lachezar, I was wondering about   the SPFx and SPFX-webparts tags in your quest. Do these tags mean you have some SPFx webpart on your page? I was also wondering if you get the issue only in a specific browser?

Comment: hello Denis,

Thank you for your questions.

Yes, it is an SPFx project. The issue is not browser-specific (I reproduce it in Chrome, Edge and Firedox). Links have been added using a REST call to either the /_api/web/navigation/QuickLaunch endpoint, or via /_api/web/navigation/GetNodeById(${parentID})/children(${childID})/children.

Issue gets reproduced for both parent and child navlinks.